# Why does deleting the widgets in a window and then creating them again yield strange error messages in PyGObject?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I have a window and I want a change to a value in one widget to change another widget; hence in the event handler for the widget, I "refresh" the window by deleting its widgets and creating them again. In my actual code, I have several widgets and this was my workaround to "update" them. Feel free to let me know if there is a better way to update other widgets if one of the values used to generate them changes.

In the below example, however, the widget seems to go blank and I get this message:

```
(test4.py:19274): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_remove: assertion 
'_gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) == GTK_WIDGET (container) || 
GTK_IS_ASSISTANT (container) || GTK_IS_ACTION_BAR (container) || 
GTK_IS_POPOVER_MENU (container)' failed

(test4.py:19274): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_adjustment_get_value: assertion 
'GTK_IS_ADJUSTMENT (adjustment)' failed

(test4.py:19274): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_has_focus: assertion 
'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(test4.py:19274): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_has_focus: assertion 
'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
test4.py:69: Warning: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed 
Gtk.main()
[...]
```

I have attached my code here:

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

# Documentation: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/index.html

class SpecialBox(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, GUI):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self)

        self.GUI = GUI

        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, int, int)
        self.liststore.append(["Apple", 0, 100])
        self.liststore.append(["Pear", 0, 100])
        self.liststore.append(["Orange", 0, 100])

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

        filter_name = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Fruit is good", filter_name, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(column_text)

        self.filter_low = Gtk.CellRendererSpin()
        self.filter_low.connect("edited", self.low_on_amount_edited)
        self.filter_low.set_property("editable", True)

        low_adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 99, 1, 10, 0)
        self.filter_low.set_property("adjustment", low_adjustment)

        low_spin = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Random Number", self.filter_low, text=1)
        treeview.append_column(low_spin)

        self.add(treeview)

    def low_on_amount_edited(self, widget, path, value):
        value = int(value)
        self.liststore[path][1] = value
        self.GUI.restart_window(str(value))

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.special_box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label("Number label")
        self.win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.start_window()

    def start_window(self):
        self.special_box.pack_start(SpecialBox(self), True, True, 0)
        self.window_grid.add(self.special_box)
        self.window_grid.add(self.label)
        self.win.add(self.window_grid)
        self.win.show_all()

    def restart_window(self, label="Number"):
        self.window_grid.destroy()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.special_box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        self.start_window()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The above code generates the error but for some reason the below code works fine (I essentially just replaced the above widget with a button):

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

# Documentation: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/index.html

class SpecialButton(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, GUI):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self)

        self.GUI = GUI
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.message = "Special Text"

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label(self.message)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click)
        self.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

    def on_click(self, widget):
        self.GUI.restart_window(self.message)

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label("Default label")
        self.win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.start_window()

    def start_window(self):
        self.box.pack_start(SpecialButton(self), True, True, 0)
        self.window_grid.add(self.box)
        self.window_grid.add(self.label)
        self.win.add(self.window_grid)
        self.win.show_all()

    def restart_window(self, label="Default label"):
        self.window_grid.destroy()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        self.start_window()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: You don't need to destroy the widgets and create new ones again. What is your goal on the callback `low_on_amount_edited`?

Comment: In my actual code, I have a widget that displays a graph using graph-tool where one of the arguments is a "graph" g. At the start, my GUI has this widget display a blank graph. Then through a file_opener widget, we select a file and convert it to a new "graph". Hence g has changed. Thus how would I show the new graph (which I must compute from this new "g") in the graph widget without replacing the window entirely (deleting the old window and make a new one with this updated widget). I guess set_label seems to be a special function as it updates and displays the label also...

Comment: @Jose Fonte Essentially I want "update" some rather complex widgets by changing its fields and displaying the new updated version. I seem to be able to change the fields but the new version does not show. This precisely is my problem. The Label example is simplistic since it has the set_[something] functions that update and display the new label, but my widgets do not seem to have that. How do I update a widget and display the new version?

Comment: Widgets should have setters and getters and they should have internal update methods. If you choose to remove the widget and replace it with a new instance then keep a reference to it, destroy it and then add the new one. You don't need to redo all the layout, just go the the individual widget.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're destroying a widget while an event handler of that widget is running. That widget is your `CellRendererSpin`.

When the value of this Spinbutton changes, it triggers `low_on_amount_edited)`:

```
self.filter_low.connect("edited", self.low_on_amount_edited)
```

which calls `GUI.restart_window`:

```
self.GUI.restart_window(str(value))
```

which destroys the `SpecialBox` widget and all its child widgets, including the Spinbutton:

```
self.window_grid.destroy()
```

It's no surprise that destroying a widget while it's doing something is a bad idea.

---

To fix this, you just have to postpone the call to `GUI.restart_window` until the Spinbutton's event handler has finished. To do this, you can use `idle_add`, which queues a callback to be executed by the Gtk mainloop:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib

class SpecialBox(Gtk.Box):
    def low_on_amount_edited(self, widget, path, value):
        value = int(value)
        self.liststore[path][1] = value
        Gdk.threads_add_idle(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, self.GUI.restart_window, str(value))
```